# Tempertures below zero degrees Kelvin

Tags: physics, hard-science, temperature

For years I have wondered why Science does not consider temperatures (and their effects) below zero degrees Kelvin..

Would these temperatures help to explain things like dark energy, dark matter, and/or their effects on/by/of gravity?

What is below zero degrees Kelvin?

Why is science not exploring the effects of sub atomic particles on below zero degrees Kelvin?

Is there a word for temperatures below 0 degrees Kelvin? -Like Anti-Kelvin?
Thank you, 
Moe in Canada

Comment: Should really be on Physics.SE.

Comment: @PhilipRowlands It can perhaps be on-topic as a question about a particular mechanic to incorporate in a universe. But yeah.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be something for physics SE (though it may not fit their standards). It may be on-topic here as "alternative physics", but it is not asked in that way.

Comment: Compare [negative temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature): *In physics, certain systems can achieve negative temperature; that is, their thermodynamic temperature can be **expressed as a negative quantity on the Kelvin or Rankine scales.***

Answer (score 11):

Temperature is a measure of how much the atoms vibrate and move (e.g. kinetic energy). 0 Kelvin is defined as the point where the atoms do not vibrate any more at all, so you can not really have sub-kelvin temperatures, as it is not possible to move less than standing totally still. If you somehow discover that atoms at what we now believe is absolute zero actually move a little, your new temperature is just defined as the new 0 Kelvin.

A second consideration is that negative degrees Kelvin allows for heat flow that reduces [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy), a pretty important violation of physics, as that allows for infinite energy, perpetual motion machines, etc.

In short, negative absolute temperatures can not exist in reality, and in a sci-fi setting, it is likely to have a lot of unexpected consequences, having a good chance to somehow destroy the universe.

Comment: A nitpick - " If you somehow discover that atoms at what we now believe is absolute zero actually move a little, your new temperature is just defined as the new 0 Kelvin." is not true. For localized matter, the motion can never reach absolute rest, since this would violate Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle (delta v cannot be zero unless delta p is infinite).

Answer (score 2):

We actually do consider such concepts, like I got from this quick search: [Below Absolute Zero: Negative Temperatures Explained](http://www.physicscentral.com/explore/action/negative-temperature.cfm).

In the most general terms, temperature is a measure of the amount of movement of particles.  You cannot have less than 0 movement, for exactly the same reason you cannot have fewer than 0 eggs in your basket.  Numerically, we treat it as a "norm," which is a measure of distance.  Distances are never negative in physics.

However, when you get down into the weeds, it has to get redefined to handle more exotic situations.  Temperature is also often defined as a partial derivitive: $T=\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}$, where U is the internal energy of the system (all energy except kinetic energy of the system  as a whole and energy from external fields) and S is the entropy of the system.  It turns out that, with some clever manipulations, as shown in the link above, you can get into some very strange metastable states whose behavior is well defined as a "negative temperature."

These structures have really really odd behavior.  For example, If you have an atom at -5K, and you hit it with an atom at 1K, heat energy will transfer from the *colder* atom to the hotter atom!  You never see this in normal thermodynamic scenarios; energy always flows from hot to cold, but in these strange exotic situations with these metastable states, the math works out, and the experimental evidence collaborates the theory.